# System call not working in C++ for avconv

Tags: c++, system-calls, avconv

I am using system call in C++ for writing short 30 sec video files from sequence of images, the virtual memory is steadily increasing in raspberry pi and system calls also stopped working after certain time(appx after creating 300 Videos).

```
 sprintf(cmdtorun, "avconv -framerate %d -i %s -c:v libvpx -qmin 20 -qmax 30 -an -threads 2 -c:a libvorbis -r %d %s",
                this->getFPS(),imgseq,this->getFPS(),vidname);
                int status;
                if(status = system(cmdtorun)){
                    printf("system command cmdtorun failed: (%i) \n",status );
                }
                else printf("cmdtorun successful\n");
```

Comment: What happens if you write out the same video to different filenames in a loop?

Comment: When you say "the virtual memory is steadily increasing", do you mean "of your process", or do you mean "of the system in general"?

Comment: Is avconv launching a helper program which is continuing to exist in memory?  (What does ps axf say?)

Comment: are your sure it's c++ problem? I'm not familiar with this avconv tool, but it somehow feels like this is a problem with calls to converter itself (aside from c++). I would suggest to try doing the same in some dynamic prototype-friendly language (python, lua, bash, etc.) or even repeating the same by hands if possible and see if problem persists. 
narrow down domain of your problem.

Comment: @Martin Bonner yes of the process. Actually the problem is that after some time the system call is unable to create video files and I also observe that virtual memory is also increased from 120M to 980M usage, so may be there is some correlation between two. Everything works fine but all system calls in program stops working e.g rm, avconv.

Comment: avconv is also not running.(ps axf)

Comment: I suspect that it's not the call to system which is leaking memory.  You are doing something in a loop, which consumes memory, and you are leaking each time round the loop.  Try a) writing out the same image in a loop (ie, just the call to system is in the loop); b) commenting out the call to system (and just leaving the printfs)

Comment: @Martin Bonner strangely the problem was with system command. I used popen instead of system call it is working fine now and memory usage also low and stable as compared to system call. couldn't figure out what was the problem with system call. Can it be a problem with OS or device?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by using popen instead of system call.